# How can I make a report that shows the credit limit for country?

Tags: report, odoo

For a homework of Odoo course:

How can I make a **report that shows the credit limit for country** of the customers in Odoo13 that shows the information in a **tree view (list view) and a graphic view**?

Is it possible to do it using Customized Views ("Technical>User Interface>Customized views") or I need to install a new Odoo App to make it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @hongsy, is that better? It is my first time using Odoo and I have no idea of how I can do this report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you saied  Technical>User Interface>Customized views 
you juste need to create a new view that read from your module and add it to your module's menu with new action and in action type you put tree , pivot,graph